# SQL Server : stored procedure parameter truncated while using dynamic query

Tags: sql-server

I am using a dynamic stored procedure, the parameter value is really long (more than 8000 characters).

And another stored procedure is calling inside the dynamic query (`@SP`), when I execute the SP the parameter being truncated.

How can I get the entire parameter? Did I miss some thing??

Because of this I am unable to execute the query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].["SP_NAME"]
    @ID varchar(50),
    @<parameter> nvarchar(max), 
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @SP nvarchar(MAX)
   set @SP = '

   DECLARE @sampleNVARCHAR nvarchar(MAX)
   SET @sampleNVARCHAR= '''+ @<parameter>+ '''

   EXEC <anotherSP> @sampleNVARCHAR,'+ cast(@CLIENTOFFSET as varchar(10)) +''

   EXEC sp_executesql @SP
   RETURN
```

Comment: How are the parameters to `anotherSP` declared?

Comment: Try printing the `@<parameter>` in the sp body. Is it printing all the 8000 characters?

Comment: anotherSP have two parameters only.
@<parameter> getting from the main SP(SP_NAME) and its assigned to @sampleNVARCHAR, and next is datetime

Comment: Is the nested stored procedure also having nvarchar(max) param size?  Also, are you really combing varchar and nvarchar?

Comment: @MikeM yeah the nested SP also having nvarchar(max).no. i just tried to combine nvarchar(max) to another nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lead of the concatenation with a `nvarchar(max)` variable it will work for you.

Set `@SP` to an empty string and the use `@SP` in the concatenation expression.

```
declare @SP nvarchar(max);
set @SP = '';
set @SP = @SP + N'declare @sample....' + @Param
```

A test you can run on your own machine or in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17371)

```
declare @SP nvarchar(max)
declare @Param nvarchar(max) = 'ParamString'

set @SP = replicate(N'X', 3000) + replicate(N'Y', 3000) + @Param
select len(@SP) -- Truncated to 4011 characters

set @SP = ''
set @SP = @SP + replicate(N'X', 3000) + replicate(N'Y', 3000) + @Param
select len(@SP) -- Not truncated, shows 6011 characters
```

Answer (score 3):

The 8000 character limit does not applies to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` ,  you can specify upto **n=4000** characters if you are **EXPLICITLY** specifying `NVarchar(N)` and upto **N=8000** characters if you are using `VARCHAR(N).`

`NVarchar(MAX)` and `Varchar(MAX)` can only hold up to 65535 bytes  which comes out to more than 2 billion characters .

If error being thrown shows string truncated message , check inside inner stored procedure for truncation error.

Comment: Actually,i tried to PRINT @SP in this SP.here itself it was trimmed off.

Comment: Print only supports up to 8000 characters.  The rest of the data is probably there.

Comment: yeah...but when i tried through the application,got the syntax error because of the parameter no completed

Comment: That middle paragraph is nonsense. Where did you come up with that 65535 number? Also, even the 2GB limit doesn't apply to `varchar(max)` *variables*.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Thanks. It was driving me crazy, I didn't know why an NVARCHAR(MAX) input parameter was truncating the input to 65,535 characters. Now I know that the information was there, it was just the SELECT that represented it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This can be because of **implicit conversion**

Implicit conversions are not visible to us.
SQL Server automatically converts the data from one data type to another. 
For example, when a smallint is compared to an int, the smallint is implicitly converted to int before the comparison proceeds.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting the paramater in the text of the dynamic query is possible to pass them as parameters too, `@CLIENTOFFSET` is not defined in the OP script, the value is invented

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].["SP_NAME"]
    @ID varchar(50),
    @<parameter> nvarchar(max), 
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @SP nvarchar(MAX)
   set @SP = '

   DECLARE @sampleNVARCHAR nvarchar(MAX)
   SET @sampleNVARCHAR= @param

   EXEC <anotherSP> @sampleNVARCHAR, cast(@CLIENTOFFSET as varchar(10))'

   EXEC sp_executesql @SP, N'@param nvarchar(max), @CLIENTOFFSET int'
      , @param = @<parameter>, @CLIENTOFFSET = @ID
   RETURN
```

The see the full definition of `sp_executesql` its [technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is probably the best choice